# What are the Integration-by-parts steps needed to get from Equation 1 to 2?

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I need help justifying the jump from the expression on the left side of the equal sign, to the right.

\begin{array},\int_0^L  \mathrm{d}x \ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (T(x) \frac{\partial y}{\partial t})\,   =  \int_0^L \!\mathrm{d}x \ T(x) \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})\,
\end{array}

The preceding passage - in the book from which the problem hails - claims to use integration by parts to do so, but I can't seem to cancel out the right terms after employing the product rule...
\begin{array}1
\int_0^L \! \mathrm{d}x \   \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [  \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}   \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + T   \frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x^2}]
\end{array}
Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts allows to switch a derivative from one factor to another...

$$
\int_a^b u'(x) v(x) dx = \left[u(x)v(x)\right]_a^b - \int_a^b u(x) v'(x) dx
$$

Are you sure about the formula you posted? There should be a minus sign in the RHS.
Also, since there are no boundary terms  on the RHS, there must be some assumption on $T$ or $y$ that makes them go away.